# Remove namespaces from xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have written a program to create an xml document from an excel but it is outputting the following format (notice the xmls="" on the key and value nodes (i don't want this))

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Content xmlns="uuid:5c2dffe6-cf72-4211-a8a0-dc6a7baf3ff1">
  <Redirect xmlns="xmlns:xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <key xmlns="">/*$0*/</key>
    <value xmlns="">/</value>
  </Redirect>
  <Redirect xmlns="xmlns:xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <key xmlns="">/2014-12-22</key>
    <value xmlns="">/</value>
  </Redirect>
  <Redirect xmlns="xmlns:xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <key xmlns="">/a</key>
    <value xmlns="">/</value>
  </Redirect>
</Content>
```

desired format notice the key and value nodes dont have xmlns=""

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:5c2dffe6-cf72-4211-a8a0-dc6a7baf3ff1">
  <Redirect xmlns="xmlns:xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <key>/*$0*/</key>
    <value>/</value>
  </Redirect>
  <Redirect xmlns="xmlns:xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <key>/2014-12-22</key>
    <value>/</value>
  </Redirect>
  <Redirect xmlns="xmlns:xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <key>/a</key>
    <value>/</value>
  </Redirect>
</Content>
```

my code

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lblFileUploaded.Text != "No_File_has_been_uploaded")
    {

        if (ddlHostName.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please_select_a_host_name");

        }
        else
        {
            var hostName = ddlHostName.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //"Content" + "xmlns=\"uuid:5c2dffe6-cf72-4211-a8a0-dc6a7baf3ff1\""

            XNamespace ns = "uuid:5c2dffe6-cf72-4211-a8a0-dc6a7baf3ff1";
            var rootNode = new XElement(ns + "Content");

            var processedUrls = new HashSet<string>();

            //select the file thats been uploaded

            var file = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            if (!file.Exists)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (file.Extension != ".xlsx")
            {
                lblFileUploaded.Text = "ERROR__File_format_invalid";
                return;
            }

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                var workbook = package.Workbook;
                var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];

                int lastRow = sheet.Dimension.End.Row;

                //loop through the xsls rows of data
                for (int i = 2; i < lastRow; i++)
                {
                    var oldUrl = sheet.Cells[i, 1].Text.Trim();
                    var newUrl = sheet.Cells[i, 2].Text.Trim();

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldUrl) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newUrl) || processedUrls.Contains(oldUrl))
                        continue;

                    processedUrls.Add(oldUrl);

                    XNamespace ns2 = "xmlns:xlink=" + "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
                    var urlChildNode = new XElement( ns2 + "Redirect");
                    rootNode.Add(urlChildNode);

                    var urlOldNode = new XElement("key", oldUrl.Replace(hostName, ""));
                    urlChildNode.Add(urlOldNode);

                    if (newUrl.Equals(hostName + "/"))
                    {
                        var urlNewNode = new XElement("value", newUrl.Replace(hostName + "/", "/"));
                        urlChildNode.Add(urlNewNode);
                    }

                    else if (newUrl.Equals(hostName))
                    {
                        var urlNewNode = new XElement("value", newUrl.Replace(hostName, "/"));
                        urlChildNode.Add(urlNewNode);
                    }

                    else if (newUrl.Equals("www.aircharterservice.com"))
                    {
                        var urlNewNode = new XElement("value", newUrl.Replace("www.aircharterservice.com", "/"));
                        urlChildNode.Add(urlNewNode);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        var urlNewNode = new XElement("value", newUrl.Replace(hostName, ""));
                        urlChildNode.Add(urlNewNode);
                    }

                }
            }
```

At the moment i am struggling to see how i can remove the unwanted namespace

Comment: `"key"` -> `ns2+"key"`, `"value"` -> `ns2+"value"`.

Comment: Awesome worked a treat, thank you so much. No more using find and replace now i have the solution. could you explain how that works please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child elements inherit default namespace from parent. So, this xml code:

```
<parent xmlns="Namespace">
    <child />
</parent>
```

equivalent to:

```
<parent xmlns="Namespace">
    <child xmlns="Namespace" />
</parent>
```

but not to:

```
<parent xmlns="Namespace">
    <child xmlns="" />
</parent>
```

Thus, if you want to remove `xmlns=""` attribute from `child` element, then you have to put `child` element in the same namespace as `parent` element, but not to empty namespace.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the help above the following code helped me solve the issue.

```
XNamespace ns2 = "xmlns:xlink=" + "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
var urlChildNode = new XElement( ns2 + "Redirect");
rootNode.Add(urlChildNode);

var urlOldNode = new XElement(ns2 + "key", oldUrl.Replace(hostName, ""));
urlChildNode.Add(urlOldNode);

if (newUrl.Equals(hostName + "/"))
{
    var urlNewNode = new XElement(ns2 + "value", newUrl.Replace(hostName + "/", "/"));
    urlChildNode.Add(urlNewNode);
}

else if (newUrl.Equals(hostName))
{
    var urlNewNode = new XElement(ns2 + "value", newUrl.Replace(hostName, "/"));
    urlChildNode.Add(urlNewNode);
}

else if (newUrl.Equals("www.aircharterservice.com"))
{
    var urlNewNode = new XElement(ns2 + "value", newUrl.Replace("www.aircharterservice.com", "/"));
    urlChildNode.Add(urlNewNode);
}

else
{
    var urlNewNode = new XElement(ns2 + "value", newUrl.Replace(hostName, ""));
    urlChildNode.Add(urlNewNode);
}
```

Comment: Your `xlink` namespace is almost certainly wrong. It should probably not have the `xmlns:xlink=` as part of the namespace.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your input. I was just asked to create a little program that would create an xml document based on the format specified above and i now have that :)

Comment: No, I think you read the format incorrectly. Please look carefully. Search on [so] for "xlink xmlns" for many examples of the correct namespace.